# Android pass data between Broadcast Receivers

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am creating an app that records calls. I have created 2 receivers, one for listening phone state and other for getting outgoing call number. I could detect outgoing calls from the 1st receiver. But I could not get outgoing call number from the 1st receiver. So I had to create a 2nd receiver that processes outgoing calls from where I can get the phone number. But I would like to send the outgoing call phone number to 1st receiver from 2nd receiver. How do I do that? I tried sending broadcast via Intent, but I got an exception. Any other way I can send data from one receiver to another?

*Manifest*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.js.globemaster.autocallrecorder">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

*OutgoingCallReceiver.java*

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String phonenumber;
    private SaveObject saveObject;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        saveObject = SaveObject.getInstance();
        saveObject.setOutgoingnumber(phonenumber);
        Log.e("Outgoing", phonenumber);

    }
}
```

*IncomingReceiver.java:*

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create one `CallReceiver` with next `intent-filter`'s:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".CallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in your `CallReceiver` try to do this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.equals(action)) {
        // It is outgoing call
        String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        // You can save this phoneNumber in sharedPreferences for further using
    } else if (ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        // Get here your phoneNumber from sharedPreferences and use it

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

        }
    }
}
```